# Meteor and React - Componentdidmount, multiple Meteor.calls and setstate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, setstate

I'm trying to get specific user details with meteor calls (they need to be fetched server-side for security reasons) and set the result into states. What I'm trying now is:

```
componentDidMount(){
    Meteor.call('getCurrentCF', this.state.currentAccount, (err, res) => {
        if (!err) {
            var result = JSON.parse(res.content);
            if (typeof result.cfu['destinations'] != 'undefined') {

                if(result.cfu['destinations'][0].destination === "voicebox") {
                    this.setState({
                        cfActive: 'btn btn-block btn-maik',
                        vbActive: 'btn btn-block btn-maik-active',
                    });
                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        cfActive: 'btn btn-block btn-maik-active',
                        vbActive: 'btn btn-block btn-maik',
                        currentCFDest: "(" + result.cfu['destinations'][0].simple_destination + ")",
                    });
                }

            } else {
                this.setState({
                    cfActive: 'btn btn-block btn-maik',
                    vbActive: 'btn btn-block btn-maik',
                });
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Error: " + err);
        }
    });

    Meteor.call('getCurrentVM', this.state.currentAccount, (err, res) => {
        if(!err) {
            var vms = JSON.parse(res.content);

            this.setState({
                vmCount: vms.total_count,
            });
        } else {
            console.log(err)
        }
    });

    this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
    });
}
```

But when trying this, I get an console error messsage:

> Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually
>   means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an
>   unmounted component. This is a no-op.

It all works, but it is sending error messages to the browsers console which I don't want. What would be the correct way to get this working the right way?

Comment: If this data is about users, assuming is coming from a collection, is there a reason why not to do so with a publication?

Comment: @user7386177 no it’s not coming from a collection. Data is fetched from an external API using a meteor method (HTTP.call()). This data is then returned and is used to set states for further use in the app.

Comment: I am using the same approach as you for something similar but using a conditional rendering function, since children components dependent on that data as well. Are you using such a thing as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen when your callback resolves after unmounting your component. To avoid this behaviour you would have to track if your component is still mounted. This can be done by setting flag to `true` on mount and then `false` on unmount. [More info here.](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html)

Comment: I read the article but I'm not sure as of why the component is unmounted during this process. I've read that setState() causes a rerender, but if only one setState() is used in ComponentdidMount(), this already causes this error.

Comment: @Maikey re-render doesn't mean it will be unmounted; unmounting happens when component has been removed from virtual dom. Easiest way to debug would be to set debugger in componentWillUnmount

Comment: I got it working. Thanks! I overlooked the fact that I'm doing a check if a user is logged in and if not, this.props.history is set to the login page. This is where it actually goes wrong. To solve it, I've created a state isMounted and given it an initial value of _false_. Should a user be logged in, this is set to _true_. In ComponentdidMount the **Meteor.call** is only executed, if the value of isMounted is _true_.